# HOW TO CONFIG SHARE KIT FOR FACEBOOK IOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, sharekit

I Don't understand  how to configure facebook in share kit, i was checking this

http://getsharekit.com/install

and i've read `SHKConfig.h` and do the same as it was mentioned but still not working

```
#define SHKFacebookUseSessionProxy  NO
#define SHKFacebookKey              @"486013621487743"
#define SHKFacebookSecret           @""
#define SHKFacebookSessionProxyURL  @""
```

I just did this .

when i click on facebook it just open in simulator but cant post the selected picture or text. kindly tell me the best possible solution

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of ShareKit from your link has not been updated for a long time. You can try updated [ShareKit 2](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/). Installation is a little bit different, make sure to follow [install guide](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit) literally.